# SSIS Package file with Local C drive vs network drive

Tags: ssis

I create simple ssis package to import data from Access mdb.
Using OLEDB source to connect the mdb file and OLEDB destination on SQL server.
I create sql agent job job to run the the package.
If I used file on local c drive then it's working ( able to import data).
If I used the file on network then it will not working (the error said not see the file on network)
Some people said need to use UNC path \server\xxx\xxxx
However on visual studio to create the package and  dont see how to use UNC network path on OLEDB connection file.
Can someone can help me with this issue. Many thanks.

Comment: Where are you defining the connection right now for C Drive? Surely at some point you already set this C drive connection up? Just change that

Comment: I think I solve the issue on network side. need to use correct UNC path \\server\xxx\xxxx